# Отправить форму игнорируя маску, если не введен телефон

Tags: javascript, jquery

1. Создана форма с полем имя, телефон, email, город, сообщение. Поля  имя, email, город - обязательные для заполнения (required). Поле сообщение и телефон - не обязательные для заполнения.
2. Поле телефон `<input type="tel"  class="inputbox"  id="clientPhone" name="telephone"/>`
3. добавлена библиотека jquery.min.js для отображение маски телефона 
   `$("#clientPhone").mask("+38(999)999-99-99");`

4.Вопрос: если поле телефон не заполнено форма не отправляется, как написать проверку для отправки формы когда поле телефон не заполнено (чтоб не учитывало маску телефона), чтобы осуществить возможность отправки формы без введенного телефона?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#btn-send').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var telephone = $('#clientPhone').val();
    if (telephone == "") {
      $('#clientPhone').addClass('Valid');
      return true;
    }

    //Проверка поля Имя 
    else {
      var name = $('#clientName').val();
      if (name.length < 2) {
        $('#clientName').addClass('notValid');
        $(this).next().text('Введите, пожалуйста, Ваше имя, не менее двух символов').fadeOut(10000);
        return false;
      }


      //Проверка поля Город
      else {
        var city = $('#clientCity').val();
        if (city.length < 2) {
          $('#clientCity').addClass('notValid');
          $(this).next().text('Введите, пожалуйста, название Города, не менее двух символов');
          return false;
        }


        //Проверка поля email 
        else {

          var email = $('#clientEmail').val();
          var filter = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,6})+$/;
          if (filter.test(email) == false) {
            $('#clientEmail').addClass('notValid');
            $(this).next().text('Заполните, пожалуйста, поле e-mail. Пример формата поля e-mail: test@test.test');
            return false;
          }


          //отправка формы если все ок
          else {

            $('#userFeedback').submit(); // отправляем форму
            msg = 'Спасибо, Ваша заявка принята. С Вами свяжутся в ближайшее время';
            result = msg;
            $("#userFeedback").html(result);

          }
        }
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Огрызки кода несъедобны.

Comment: Добро пожаловать на StackOverflow. Посмотрите внимательно на код в Вашем вопросе и добавьте пропущеный блок `if`.

Comment: Позвольте поинтересоваться: а по какой причине нельзя использовать HTML-атрибут placeholder совместно с атрибутом pattern?!

Comment: Библиотека `jquery.min.js` или `jquery.maskedinput.min.js` ? http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin

Answer (score 0):

У вас в коде ошибка которая блокирует дальнейшее выполнение скрипта:

```
var telephone = $('#clientPhone').val();
if (telephone === "") { // и да тут лучше использовать тройное равенство.
  $('#clientPhone').addClass('Valid');
  return true; // Вот эта строка вам не дает дальше делать действие, удалите ее и все станет на свои места
}
```

Comment: Там всё равно else ;)